# tikzexternal no pdf output

Tags: pdf, tikz-external

I am trying to use tikzexternal to produce pdf of my images. I was using `tikzpicture` in `\begin{figure}` environment. However, I could not get any pdf output. Then I removed the `\begin{figure}`, tried again and no pdf output. I have checked the logfile from "logs and other files". It seems that I am using shell-escape option. I do not know what is the problem.

I am pasting my code here. Maybe there are other libraries causing the conflict. I do not know. Btw, I am using overleaf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{color}
\xyoption{color}
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}
\newcommand\dboxed[1]{\dbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark,
    fit
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\tikzset{
    mycirc/.style={circle, draw=black, thick, outer sep=0, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5ex},
    mytext/.style={text=black, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt}
}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{Figure}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\maketitle

%\begin{figure}[H]
    %\centering
   % \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Images/hirarchy.png}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \filldraw[inner color=pink,draw=black] (2,2) circle (3cm);
     \path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={something},text align=center}]  (4,2) arc [start angle= 0,end angle=-360,radius=2];
     \draw[inner color = blue ,draw = black] (3,2) circle (2cm);
     \path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={something},text align=center}]  (5,2) arc [start angle= 0,end angle=-360,radius=1.4];
    \draw[inner color = pink,outer color=pink,draw = black] (4,2) circle (1cm) node {something};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{there was a long caption here}
    %\label{fig:hirarchy}
%\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: which engine do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You imported a lot of unnecessary or duplicated packages which can result in conflicts. Next time you also should report the error messages. I removed some of the packages and this is what worked for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{dashbox}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{qcircuit}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{color}
\xyoption{color}
\def\imagetop#1{\vtop{\null\hbox{#1}}}
\newcommand\dboxed[1]{\dbox{\ensuremath{#1}}}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
%\usepackage{pst-node, pst-arrow}
%\usepackage{environ}
%\usepackage{adjustbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mathcircled[1]{%
  \mathpalette\@mathcircled{#1}%
}
\newcommand\@mathcircled[2]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(math.base)] \node[draw,circle,inner sep=1pt] (math) {$\m@th#1#2$};%
}
\usetikzlibrary{
    arrows,
    calc,
    chains,
    decorations,
    decorations.text,
    decorations.pathmorphing,
    matrix,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    tikzmark,
    fit
}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{circledsteps}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\tikzset{
    mycirc/.style={circle, draw=black, thick, outer sep=0, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, minimum size=1.5ex},
    mytext/.style={text=black, anchor=#1, inner sep=0, outer sep=1pt}
}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\usepackage{geometry}
\title{Figure}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Images/hirarchy.png}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
     \filldraw[inner color=pink,draw=black] (2,2) circle (3cm);
     \path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={something},text align=center}]  (4,2) arc [start angle= 0,end angle=-360,radius=2];
     \draw[inner color = blue ,draw = black] (3,2) circle (2cm);
     \path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={something},text align=center}]  (5,2) arc [start angle= 0,end angle=-360,radius=1.4];
    \draw[inner color = pink,outer color=pink,draw = black] (4,2) circle (1cm) node {something};
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \caption{there was a long caption here}
    \label{fig:hirarchy}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```